# Column Visibility in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2012 for my report. I want to hide certain columns in a report. I don't want to see spaces between columns in my report when a middle column is not visible. I have an expression that hides or make visible a certain column base on the value selected.`=IIF(CBool(Parameters!Column.Value)=True,True,False)`
But the issue I have with this is that I see spaces between columns in the table when the report is rendered.
In the image below, I want to be able to hide the Code column at the middle of the table without seeing any gap between columns in the table. Thanks for the help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you highlighted the Code column and then added the expression to the `Hidden` property in the Properties Pane?

Try right clicking on the column, selecting Column Visibility, and then entering your expression in the box under the 'Show or hide based on expression' radio button. This should collapse the column and not leave any whitespace when your parameter is set to true.